# MobileFirst JSON Store Init Error on builds w/ Android Studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Unable to Initialize JSON Store when building an apk (android-debug.apk or signed android-release.apk) with Android Studio. The same code initialized JSON Store successfully when I emulate or use the Cordova-debug.apk using MFP CLI.

Using MFP 7.1.0.00.20160217-1815

```
WL.JSONStore.init({test:{}}, {username:'abc',password:'abc'}).then(function (coll) {
           console.log('Done',coll);
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log('Setup store error', error);
        });
```

Below is the log which throws `INVALID_KEY_ON_PROVISION` error. This happens on the very first run of the app so I doubt if the error is related to invalid password. Also the init succeeds if no collections are mentioned.

```
V/WindowManager( 1298): Adding window Window{1fe251eb u0 PopupWindow:ff4fcc1} at 3 of 6 (after Window{12c29fd0 u0 com.sample.app/com.sample.app.CordovaApp})
W/EGL_emulation( 5265): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer( 5265): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe1d22080, error=EGL_SUCCESS
I/UsageStatsService( 1298): User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
D/HttpPostRequestSender( 5265): WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:42 :: Sending request http://192.168.1.124:10080/DemoRuntime/apps/services/random?bytes=32
D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils( 5265): WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:553 :: os.arch: x86_64
D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils( 5265): WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:574 :: Extracting zip file: featurelibs/x86/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils( 5265): WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:584 :: Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.sample.app/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils( 5265): WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:589 :: com.mobileiron.wrapped is set to false
D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils( 5265): WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:594 :: Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.sample.app/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
E/JSONSTORE( 5265): JSONStoreLogger.logError in JSONStoreLogger.java:189 :: Error setting key
E/JSONSTORE( 5265): com.worklight.jsonstore.exceptions.JSONStoreInvalidPasswordException: Error setting key.
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.handleUsernameAndPassword(WLJSONStore.java:232)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.provisionDatabase(WLJSONStore.java:148)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.openCollections(WLJSONStore.java:347)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.initializeCollection(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:152)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.databaseActionDispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:138)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.actionDispatch(BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.java:36)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:90)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:79)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sample.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libopenssl_fips.so"
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.security.FipsWrapper.<clinit>(FipsWrapper.java:28)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.security.SecurityUtils.encrypt(SecurityUtils.java:68)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.security.SecurityManager.storeDPK(SecurityManager.java:99)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.handleUsernameAndPassword(WLJSONStore.java:221)
E/JSONSTORE( 5265):     ... 10 more
I/chromium( 5265): [INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Setup store error", source:  (7)
E/wl.jsonstore( 5265): {"src":"initCollection","err":-3,"msg":"INVALID_KEY_ON_PROVISION","col":"test","usr":"abc","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

Comment: Did you find the problem, im having the samething with /JSONSTORE(14775): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.security.FipsWrapper... when building using ant.  builds i dont with eclipse are fine

Comment: Nope, no fix yet. I've reached out to IBM folks but haven't had any response from them. You will not get this error if you do a release build using cordova release and then sign manually using jarsigner and zipalign. There is some issue with android studio and gradle which messes up the encryption and throws this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around, I've signed the release build manually. This happens to work but the apk could be larger than when signed with android studio.
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually